# Why Does Python Method Needs a `self` pointer for Recursion to Work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, recursion

I'm new to Python and want to use it for LeetCode. I was doing a recursion problem and realized that I have to use `self.` pointer in order for the recursion to work. Here is my initial code:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        if not head or not head.next:
            return head
        
        p = reverseList(head.next)
        head.next.next = head
        head.next = None
        
        return p
```

However, this would give me an error:

```
NameError: name 'reverseList' is not defined
```

I had to add a `self.` before `reverseList()` in order for it to work. I'm curious that why Python is acting like this way? Java and C++ are all fine with recursion without a `this` pointer. It's a little bit strange, since if I declare my function outside of a class, it wouldn't need a `self` pointer for recursion to work.

Comment: `reverseList` is not a global variable; it's a class attribute, and has to be used as such.

Comment: `class` statements do not create a scope in which the name `reverseList` is defined.

Comment: There is no need to wrap this in `class Solution`; `self` refers to the object reference itself when the method is called on an object (i.e. when the function is invoked in an object context). If you drop `class Solution` and defines in as a regular function, it will work as you expect.

Comment: @MatsLindh It's cruft forced on the user by some coding-challenge site (I forget which one).

Comment: As far as I recall, there's no ambiguity in Java because the only thing `reverseList` *could* refer to is the method. C++ lets you drop `this` when it's not ambiguous, but is required if there *is* a global function by the same name as the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with recursion *per se*, but with where the name `reverseList` is defined.

Inside the function, free variables (i.e., variables not defined the function itself) are looked up in the closest enclosing scope. The `class` statement, however, does not define a new scope, so `reverseList` must be defined in the global scope if it is to be used. But you don't want anything from the global scope; you want to call the instance method. To do so, you must access it from the same instance that made the top-level call, i.e., `self`.